# Is My Etherum Wallet Synching with the Blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, myetherwallet

I just downloaded geth and started running the geth --rpc command. Is everything working and normal?

> peer=5e56002f0252fe80 number=1701275 hash=6fe05e…979f0a WARN
>   [05-16|15:29:09] Header broke chain ancestry
>   peer=5e56002f0252fe80 number=1701657 hash=4b1ecb…519ee6 WARN
>   [05-16|15:29:10] Header broke chain ancestry
>   peer=5e56002f0252fe80 number=1702403 hash=359304…d535fb WARN
>   [05-16|15:29:11] Header broke chain ancestry
>   peer=5e56002f0252fe80 number=1703158 hash=a8edf8…099703 WARN
>   [05-16|15:29:12] Header broke chain ancestry
>   peer=5e56002f0252fe80 number=1703561 hash=8b738c…823f53 WARN
>   [05-16|15:29:13] Header broke chain ancestry
>   peer=5e56002f0252fe80 number=1704121 hash=409083…b041d7 WARN
>   [05-16|15:29:13] Header broke chain ancestry
>   peer=5e56002f0252fe80 number=1704509 hash=ba83bc…6c6ca0

Got this also

> WARN [05-16|15:37:57] Synchronisation failed, retrying
>   err="receipt download canceled (requested)" INFO [05-16|15:38:01]
>   Imported new block headers               count=0    elapsed=2.979ms
>   number=1914414 hash=0f3c0d…075354 ignored=192 INFO [05-16|15:38:01]
>   Imported new block receipts              count=0    elapsed=0s
>   number=1914235 hash=4a964a…5a322a ignored=13 INFO [05-16|15:38:01]
>   Imported new block headers               count=0    elapsed=1.978ms
>   number=1914606 hash=4ff356…074458 ignored=192

I'm a total noob is everything working?

Answer (score 2):

Your chain is syncing. When you posted the message your client synced about 1/3 of the blockchain. `number` is block number. You had [1704121](https://etherscan.io/block/1704121) and head of the main net is [3719020](https://etherscan.io/).